# How to pre-complie css style sheets in rails 2.3?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, nginx, ruby-on-rails-2, staging

I have developed a new requirement for my client, I had added some css rule to an existing style-sheet file and these changes were reflecting on my local machine during development. But when I moved the changes to an staging server and restarted nginx all my functionalites are working but my css rules are not getting applied, when I checked the firebug console that particular file is getting included but my new css rules are not in there, should I pre-compile my css style-sheets if so how to do it in rails 2.3.x ...?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you do a full deploy instead of copying the files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Rails 2.3` does not have asset pipeline. So there is no need to precompile assets. Your assets should already be located in the `Rails.root/public/stylesheets` folder

Anything in `Rails.root/public/` folder is served by the `web server` directly and it does not involve rails.

Your problem is most likely some sort of caching. You can try fetching the stylesheet directly using its URL like this

```
http://server.domain/stylesheets/mystyles.css
```

and see if your changes are reflected.

You can also check your `Firebug` -> `Net` tab to see if the style sheet is being downloaded from the server (http return code: **`200 OK`**) or it is being picked up from the cache (http return code: **`304 Not Modified`**)

There are ways to handle this type of issues, which `rails 3.1 asset pipeline` incorporates.

1. Using a different file name when content changes
2. Using the ETag header
3. Appending a unique hash (calculated using timestamp of the file) as a `query string`. For example `http://domain/style.css?djfhsfhkkjdsfh` where `djfhsfhkkjdsfh` will change every time `style.css` is modified.

are couple of commonly used tricks.

If you are keen on using asset pipeline with `rails 2.3` you have options such as [Jammit](http://documentcloud.github.io/jammit/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I followed your solution by checking the firebug console, later when server was restarted it was working fine.